# I get the wrong answer to a fairly simple trig problem involving the concept of bearing

Tags: trigonometry

This is a problem from a textbook on elementary trigonometry ([Teach Yourself Trigonometry by Paul Abbott and Hugh Neill (2003)](https://www.amazon.ca/Teach-Yourself-Trigonometry-P-Abbott/dp/0071421351)). The problem is supposed to be fairly basic, but the answer I get is not what it says at the back of the book. So, either I don't understand what the concept of bearing is or something else must be wrong.

Problem:

> A boat which is on a bearing of 038° from a harbour is 6 miles north of the harbour. How far east is the boat from the harbour?

038° is the way they say 38° in marine navigation, I suppose. So, the answer has got to be the following:

> 6 miles / tan 38° ≈ 7.68 miles

But in the answers section, it says 4.69 miles. There are a couple of other similar problems involving bearings which I also get wrong answers for. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: What is the reference angle for a bearing?  I would understand that to mean  $38^{\circ}$ to the east of true north (i.e. angles are measured clockwise, with north begin the zero).  This is different from the way that mathematicians usually measure angle, which is anti-clockwise, with east begin the zero.  Making this change gives the right answer.

Comment: That seems to be correct. The author just doesn't explain how to work with bearings in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to the usual mathematical notation, bearings are measured clockwise, starting at the north.  Thus a bearing of $0^\circ$ is north, a bearing of $90^\circ$ is east, a bearing of $135^\circ$ is southeast, and so on.

[image]

From the picture, we get
$$ \tan(38^\circ) = \frac{\text{distance east}}{\text{distance north}} = \frac{x}{6}
\implies x = 6 \tan(38^{\circ}) \approx 4.69,
$$
hence the boat is about 4.69 miles to the east of the harbour.

Answer (score 1):

You should be calculating $6\times\tan38$ since bearings are measured clockwise from North.